# Trouble linking SQLite3 library (sqlite3.lib) with MinGW GCC on Windows

Tags: c, sqlite

I'm encountering difficulties linking the SQLite3 library (sqlite3.lib) with my C code using MinGW GCC on Windows. Despite my efforts, the linker fails to find the symbols from the SQLite library, resulting in unresolved references during compilation.

Here's the command I'm using for compilation:

```
gcc -o c c.c -LC:\users\tyson\desktop\g2 -lsqlite3 -lcrypt32

And here are the errors I'm receiving:
C:\Users\tyson\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgNlIW7.o:c.c:(.text+0x9f3): undefined reference to `sqlite3_open'
C:\Users\tyson\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgNlIW7.o:c.c:(.text+0xa07): undefined reference to `sqlite3_errmsg'
C:\Users\tyson\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgNlIW7.o:c.c:(.text+0xa8a): undefined reference to `sqlite3_close'
C:\Users\tyson\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgNlIW7.o:c.c:(.text+0xacf): undefined reference to `sqlite3_prepare_v2'
C:\Users\tyson\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgNlIW7.o:c.c:(.text+0xae7): undefined reference to `sqlite3_errmsg'
C:\Users\tyson\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgNlIW7.o:c.c:(.text+0xb0e): undefined reference to `sqlite3_close'
C:\Users\tyson\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgNlIW7.o:c.c:(.text+0xb41): undefined reference to `sqlite3_column_text'
C:\Users\tyson\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgNlIW7.o:c.c:(.text+0xb57): undefined reference to `sqlite3_column_text'
C:\Users\tyson\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgNlIW7.o:c.c:(.text+0xb6d): undefined reference to `sqlite3_column_text'
C:\Users\tyson\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgNlIW7.o:c.c:(.text+0xbc3): undefined reference to `sqlite3_step'
C:\Users\tyson\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgNlIW7.o:c.c:(.text+0xbdb): undefined reference to `sqlite3_finalize'
C:\Users\tyson\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgNlIW7.o:c.c:(.text+0xbe6): undefined reference to `sqlite3_close'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Is sqlite3 in the same folder as crypt32?
If it is, what happens if you rename or move crypt32?  Do you see errors related to it?
If so, then is the sqlite3 a proper DLL file?

You will need to give us a bit more information and also explain what you have already tried.

Comment: @randy stegbauer yes sqlite3.lib is with crypt32.lib inside the same directory !

something i wanna note  that i copied  the crypt32  lib file from my other machine 

which had the windows sdk and  the standard c/c++ extensions from visual code.

  the undefined references to `CryptStringToBinaryA@28' and others stopped 

showing. up after that ! 
all whats left is the above . 

now to acquire  the sqlite3.lib i followed this guide on github .

https://gist.github.com/zeljic/d8b542788b225b1bcb5fce169ee28c55

Comment: Are both DLLs in the "g2" folder?
What happens if you remove crypt32 from that folder?
I'm wondering if the compiler is finding crypt32 in a different folder.
Otherwise, double check that building sqlite3 was successful.

Comment: uhm when i remove the crypt32 i get :
 undefined reference to `CryptStringToBinaryA@28'
 undefined reference to `CryptUnprotectData@28'
but i gotta say maybe this sqlite3.lib that i compiled is made to work for visual studio compiler only and i wanna mention this rare time  wher i  had  "error sqlite3.lib not found and permission denied".

Comment: @RandyStegbauer im not really sure how to verify the sqlite3.lib file after compilating , i 'havent received no error indicating something going worng .

Comment: I'm sorry.  I've run out of ideas.  :-(

Comment: @RandyStegbauer Its alright friend , i appreciate your time  . 
my mental is doomed...

Comment: @RandyStegbauer omg i got it ,  when i builded the sqlite3,lib using the dlltool utility provided by MinGW  it worked but how come the crypt32 that i grabed from my viusal studio machine worked but not the sql lib ???
either way after almost 10 days i proceed with my life until the next problem but i hope not soon !

Comment: i legit can't catch a brake :the code execution cannot proceed because (null).DLL was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem.

Comment: You are not alone.  When I begin using a new program, I sometimes have strange problems that other people don't have.  And then with diligence, I discover my mistake or the problem simply goes away.  Be strong.  Keep moving and thinking.